# Can't get javascript to output simple addition result

Tags: javascript, addition

HTML File

```
   <body>
<form name = 'add'>
  <div name = 'add'>
    <input type="number" id='num1'>
    <input type="number" id='num2'>
    <button name = 'sum' onclick="add()"></button>
    <input type="number" id="sum">

  </div>

</form>

  <script src='additionkindergarden.js'></script>
```

JS file

```
var num1,num2,sum;

function add(){
num1 = document.getElementById('num1').value;
num2 = document.getElementById('num2').value;
sum = num1 + num2;
return document.getElementById('sum').value = sum;
}
```

Just started to code without the use of Udemy. I'm stuck here for about 5 hrs. I know its simple but I can't get my JS to connect with my HTML. I put in the number in num1 and num2 places in the HTML when I press the button the screen does a quick refresh, the numbers in num1 and num 2 disappear and the last input box is left blank. Please help with my first solo lvl. 1 coding project.

Comment: You aren't actually returning anything. You should remove the word 'return'

Comment: The problem is that clicking the button will call `add()` but also submit the form, which here will reload the page. Remove the `<form>` tags, you don't need them. Next, you need `sum = +num1 + +num2;` (otherwise 1 + 2 => 12)

Comment: @ChrisG The `value` of a [numeric input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number) is a `Number` so no conversion needed.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp I don't think that's true: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/kb5y0c4k/ (tested on Chrome and Firefox)

Comment: @ChrisG Ok. I guess you are correct. MDN says `value` is "A _Number_ representing the value of the number entered into the input".

Comment: @JohnnyMopp True, but they're referring to the value attribute you can add in the HTML, I guess.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that clicking the button will call `add()` but also submit the form, which here will reload the page. Remove the `<form>` tags, you don't need them.
Next, an input's `.value` is text, even if you have `type="number"`, which means you need to turn `num1` and `num2` into numbers first.
I also turned the sum element into a `<p>` given that it is for output, not input.

```js
var num1, num2, sum;

function add() {
  var num1String = document.getElementById('num1').value;
  var num2String = document.getElementById('num2').value;
  num1 = Number(num1String);
  num2 = Number(num2String);
  sum = num1 + num2;
  document.getElementById('sum').innerHTML = sum;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id='num1'>
<input type="number" id='num2'>
<button onclick="add()">Add</button>
<p id="sum"></p>
```

Comment: You should do the number cast when setting the variable so that the next line can remain the same.
sum = num1 + num2

Comment: @DanielGale Why?

Comment: The variables are outside the function, meaning if you also try to do a subtract later you will need to know to cast it as a number even though the variables are called num1 and num2. I would say `num1 = Number(document.getElementById('num1').value);` You could also validate that number before getting to the sum. Perhaps the user puts in 'a'. You won't find the error until you are summing at the moment.

Comment: @DanielGale I get your point, but converting to numbers in the `sum` line is much more readable and also performs the conversion right where `+` happens, which produces a different result otherwise. I'll change the variable names though.

Answer (score 0):

The big hiccup is the `<form>` element in the HTML -- it's trying to submit the page as a form's native behavior should.  The page submission reloads the page (or tries to load an expected page) which clears out your results before you can see them.

```js
var num1,num2,sum;

function add(){
  num1 = document.getElementById('num1').value;
  num2 = document.getElementById('num2').value;
  
  // input from the HTML comes back as text/strings
  // convert them into float numbers 
  // (3.14 for example vs. Integer numbers like 3)
  // Otherwise 1 + 3 would be 13 instead of 4
  sum = parseFloat(num1) + parseFloat(num2);
  
  // Update the input value with the calculated
  // sum
  // .toFixed() restricts how far the decimals will go
  // this helps curve a JS problem where 
  // 5.6 + 2.3 = 7.89999999... instead of 7.9
  document.getElementById('sum').value = sum.toFixed(2);
  
  // you don't have to return anything with this
  // function, but if anything just return true
  return true;
}
```

```html
<div name="add">
    <input type="number" id="num1">
    <input type="number" id="num2">
    <button name="sum" onclick="add()">Add</button>
    <input type="number" id="sum">
  </div>
```

Comment: You are aware that your code doesn't work, right? `.toFixed()` produces a string, so entering 3 and 4 produces `3.004.00`

Comment: @ChrisG updated to where now the .toFixed() is on the number output.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of points to be noted:

1. Form name was `add`,same as js function,which was causing `'is not a function error'`
2. Button type needs to explicitly set as `button`,else it submits the form
3. The num values from text fields needs to be parsed for actual values using `parseInt`

**JS update**

```
var num1,num2,sum;

function add(){
num1 = document.getElementById('num1').value;
num2 = document.getElementById('num2').value;
sum = parseInt(num1) + parseInt(num2);
return document.getElementById('sum').value = sum;
}
```

**HTML Update**

```
 <body>
        <form name='form'>
        <div name='add'>
        <input type="number" id='num1'>
        <input type="number" id='num2'>
        <button name="sum" type="button" onclick="add()"></button>
        <input type="number" id="sum">
        </div>
        </form>
        <script src='additionkindergarden.js'></script>
        </body>
```